# AngularJS bind live movemove event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and I've been wondering - How can I bind a mousemove event so a rectangular box shows up right next to the mouse pointer and is dynamic (changing size when moving the pointer)?

I know that jQuery selectable exists but I'm trying to avoid jQuery for this project and use Angular only.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

*EDIT:* 
Thanks all for your help! I'll make a pure JS function to do this.

Comment: For this kind of issue,one would have to do DOM manipulation anyway.I dont really see how angular api would help.angular.element api is quite limited.You could find a script that do the same thing without requiring jquery-ui though,or port selectable to pure DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses dirty checking and digest cycles to handle change events.  It was not built to handle continuous changes like tracking mouse movements.  That is one sure way of grinding your application to a slow crawl.  There are some things that jQuery is better suited for - this is one of them.